# Workflow/Acción de github falla cuando instala dependencias que usan cython

Tags: python

## Condiciones

Cuando corro la siguiente acción/workflow de  github (https://github.com/NostrumBioDiscovery/modtox/blob/restructuration/.github/workflows/current_commit.yml) encuentro el siguiente error (https://pipelines.actions.githubusercontent.com/4oTNPxefE8IqwFA8czbwqw1g81AVioAO1x4QzNHk7Yaiayzg32/_apis/pipelines/1/runs/24/signedlogcontent/3?urlExpires=2019-11-20T22%3A17%3A10.7902553Z&urlSigningMethod=HMACV1&urlSignature=V51nMyS8vz6lYMDFXPtsyMizQvsxE%2FpTsWi87LxoaWA%3D)

## Error

```
./basesetup.py:415: UserWarning: Unrecognized setuptools command ('-q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-xpa6lmm6/mdtraj-1.9.3/egg-dist-tmp-s4v4sct0'), proceeding with generating Cython sources and expanding templates
C compiler:
  ' '.join(sys.argv[1:])))
Attempting to autodetect OpenMP support... Compiler supports OpenMP
Attempting to autodetect SSE3   support... Compiler supports SSE3
Attempting to autodetect SSE4.1 support... Compiler supports SSE4.1

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 154, in save_modules
    yield saved
  File "/usr/share/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 195, in setup_context
    yield
  File "/usr/share/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 250, in run_setup
    _execfile(setup_script, ns)
  File "/usr/share/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/setuptools/sandbox.py", line 45, in _execfile
    exec(code, globals, locals)
  File "/tmp/easy_install-xpa6lmm6/mdtraj-1.9.3/setup.py", line 289, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "/usr/share/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "/usr/share/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "/usr/share/miniconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py", line 47, in <module>
    """)
RuntimeError: implement_array_function method already has a docstring
```

## Conclusión

Alguna idea de que está pasando? He intentado re-instalar setuptools, mirar que el python de conda no estuviera molestando y otras idea peró no pude solucionarlo...

Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido. Estás en Stack Overflow en español. Traduce tu pregunta para evitar que la cierren o llévala al sitio en inglés.

Comment: ok! Hecho! Gracias (: